# Stop certain websites from using local cache in Firefox

Tags: firefox, browser-cache

In Firefox you can limit the amount of data that's allowed to be stored in the local cache, or you can let Firefox manage it.

Is there was a way to set it to not cache anything from certain sites - like sites you were working on developing so that you always got the most recent updates?

If this isn't available in Firefox is there an alternative way to do this in Chrome ?

Comment: Why don't you use Private Browsing for those sites?

Comment: Can i have a setting that says 'if i visit this-site.com then view it in private automatically' or do i have go into private mode manually each time ?

Comment: I don't know about a setting but you could use the command line this way: `firefox -private www.google.com` in Linux or `firefox.exe -private www.google.com` in Windows. See [Command Line Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Command_Line_Options) for details.